# How to add value in new array from another array

Tags: javascript

I have a function with an argument and it's type is an array.
now I want to add value into another array using loop. but I am not able to do it as I am new to JavaScript. following is my code:

```
var entry = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,"Apple",60,65,70,"Guava"]
function entryComponent(abc) {
    // console.log("entry")
    /*for() {
        var blankArray = []     
    }*/
}
entryComponent(entry)
```

Comment: What is the expected output? If you just want to copy the array then `const blankArray = entry.slice(0);` will do that. To insert something at an index look at [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: To create a new array from some of the items in the old array, use .filter...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
array_map()
```

is what you need.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Or if you just want to loop through the array and push values to a new array based on a condition use `filter()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```js
var entry = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,"Apple",60,65,70,"Guava"]

const newArray = entry.map(x => {
    //Do something with x
    return x;
});

console.log(newArray);

// or with filter:
// This writes all numbers to new array
const secondArray = entry.filter(x => typeof(x) === 'number');

console.log(secondArray);
```

Comment: Can we do it using for loop?

Comment: `const newArray = entry.slice(0);` would do the same as you do here

Comment: It is a loop, as you can see in the snippet and the documentation.
array_map loops through the array, does something to each element and saves the result in the newArray. In my example it just copies all elements unchanged which is probably not what you want but since you didn't say what exactly you want do do in your loop..

Comment: To insert something somewhere in the array, use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: @mplungjan yes of course but that's not what he asked for, he wanted to loop through the array, thats what array_map does not slice()
Of course my example doesnt do anything else than just copying every element, but it's just a demonstration...

Comment: So let's wait for this poor question to become a better one before we close as dupe or answer what OP actually needs :)